# jdt.core CodeFormatter - formatting blocks of comments

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt, formatter

I am using org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter class. I have problem with formatting properly comments.
Can anyone tell what options from DefaultCodeFormatterConstants should I use to format properly comment blocks?

I have such situation:

```
/**
Project: some-project
@author: author
@since: 2019-01-15
*/
```

I'd like to format it to

```
/**
 * Project: some-project
 * @author: author
 * @since: 2019-01-15
 */
```

Or even how to format blocks of comments, as in my case those are not formatted at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it is not related to DefaultCodeFormatterConstants options but to CodeFormatter 'kind' property when calling format function.
So if you want to format class with comments as well you should use options like for example this:

```
CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT | CodeFormatter.F_INCLUDE_COMMENTS
```

```
final TextEdit edit = codeFormatter.format(
                CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT | CodeFormatter.F_INCLUDE_COMMENTS, // format a compilation unit
                contentToFormat, // source to format
                0, // starting position
                contentToFormat.length(), // length
                0, // initial indentation
                System.getProperty("line.separator") // line separator
        );
```